# Unable to customize focal image with Libguestfs

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I downloaded `focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img` and I am trying to pre-install software on it in order to create a template in proxmox.  When I run `virt-customize --install ...`, it fails with "No space left on device".  So I then tried to use `virt-resize` to increase the size of `/dev/sda1`.  However, it fails on boot because the partitions are re-ordered (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1472039).  I didn't think what I was doing was uncommon, but I'm stuck.  What am I missing? What are other's doing?

Answer (score 0):

i think ou should be able to install small packages in size using this tool, but keep in mind if you are copying package files with virt-copy-in or virt-customize --copy-in commands, be sure to remove them after your installation complete, it may help to free up your space in the qcow2 or img of OS file.

and actually you can run a df -h or lsblk on the OS image using this command :

```
virt-customize --run-command 'lsblk' or virt-customize --run-command 'df -h'
```

to find out how much space you have left on your image,

you can also resize the image using this command :

```
qemu-img resize image_name +100M (This command adds 100 more MB to you image)
```